# Windows application shortcut icon cannot be removed

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

I recently installed an application on my Windows 7 desktop. After the install this application created a strange icon on my desktop which cannot be removed/deleted or renamed. I find this quite intrusive and I keep wondering if this is a normal/legal case... Is an application allowed to do this? I don't remember having an option to allow this "Chuck Norris" icon on my desktop.

Any information on this will be highly appreciated.

Edit: What this icon does is when you drag over a file it applies some "deep removal" of it. It's context menu is limited to "Open" (which does nothing) and "Create shortcut"

Comment: I think I ran into a situation where I couldn't delete an icon from my desktop.  I believe the problem was that the application itself wasn't actually there.

Comment: Also, what happens when you try to delete it?

Comment: Nothing happens. Also the context menu is limited to "Open" (which does nothing) and "Create shortcut"

Comment: single click on it and press the delete key

Comment: Really? I really know how to delete a file :)

Answer (score 0):

That is not normal behavior for legitimate applications. Have you considered that it might be malware or a Trojan? if you can't uninstall it from the `Programs and Features` dialog or a simple delete of the file then I would definitely be suspecting malware.

If the application is just a shredder/secure deleter then I see no reason why it should stop itself from being deleted.

An option is to boot into [Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/Start-your-computer-in-safe-mode) and try to delete it from there.

Comment: It is not malware; my (big) company has a policy to have this application installed. Basically it is a shredder, yeah :)

Answer (score 0):

The application registered a shell extension in order to display the icon. You can remove the extension using the [Autoruns tool from sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx).

If nothing is suspicious, check out [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistadesktopui/thread/127fa814-19f6-49c6-b67a-a89dc3783dd8). Essentially, delete suspicious keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace` in registry.

More related questions: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Deskto+NameSpace+site%3Asuperuser.com

Comment: I'm sure there are ways to delete the icon, but I'm not interested in those. My original question is if this is legal/normal

Comment: No legal questions on superuser I think.